# GitHub actions: why 'Cache restored successfully' but 'cache-hit' got 'false' problem

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm experiencing CI using GitHub action.

I had a problem with installing dependencies on every CI and found that I could solve this with `actions/cache`.

Here is my part of action.yaml

```yaml
- name: Cache npm dependency
  uses: actions/cache@v3
  id: npm-cache
  with:
    path: ~/.npm
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-npm-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
    restore-keys: |
      ${{ runner.os }}-npm-

- if: steps.npm-cache.outputs.cache-hit != true
  name: Install Dependency
  run: |
    echo 'npm cache missed'
    npm ci
```

And restore the cache in `Cache npm dependency` step.

```
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: Linux-npm-...
```

But it always reinstalls dependencies in 'Install Dependency' step.

```
Run echo 'npm cache missed'
  echo 'npm cache missed'
  npm ci
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
npm cache missed
> nodemon@2.0.16 ...
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0
added 661 packages in 19.862s
```

As a result, caching becomes meaningless.
What am i missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Unless there's a good reason, use the input `cache: npm` with the `action/setup-node` action and remove your custom caching.

Comment: @rethab I tried that and i got same result.

Comment: Can you please create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @rethab I solved it by modifying it like this: `!= true` `!= 'true'` :)
But my intention was 'node_module' caching, which is not recommended in the doc, so I'm struggling this.


'It is not recommended to cache node_modules, as it can break across Node'

versions and won't work with npm ci
link: https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#node---npm

Comment: Can you still not use `cache: npm`?

Comment: Problem solved then?

Comment: @rethab yes. And solved it by using with `!= 'true'`

Comment: Please create an answer and mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by modifying it like this: `!= true` -> `!= 'true'`

Comment: I can't seem to hit cache with ```!= 'true'```, hour ago I was able to hit it

Answer (score 1):

I am using action [cache/restore](https://github.com/actions/cache/tree/main/restore) for getting data from the cache, but the mechanic is similar to the general action.

So in my case, I run into the same frustrating situation, until finally noticed a message in the documentation:

> Note cache-hit will be set to true only when cache hit occurs for the exact key match. For a partial key match via restore-keys or a cache miss, it will be set to false

That means that if your cache name did not find an exact match and instead was loaded another cache by a relative key, `cache-hit` will be `false` despite it saying the opposite in the log!

For example:

```
key: dev-npm-v5
restore-keys: dev-npm
```

But actual log will say:

```
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: dev-npm-v4
```

In that case your `cache-hit` output is `false`, but `cache-matched-key` is `dev-npm-v4`

So carefully check the requested name vs actually retrieved cache name. I ended up adding a bash script to determine if at least some cache was loaded using `cache-matched-key` variable.

Hope it helps anyone. Wasted hours trying to debug this behaviour by myself: 3